# Is there a way to overlay two similar UV islands with identical vertex count?

Tags: uv

Sometimes UV unwrap has several nearly identica islands. However, more often than not they differ a little. If I want to keep identical texture for these -- is there a good way to overlap them perfectly? I know I can do it vertex by vertex, but I hope there is a better way.

I know I can do it for the whole model if it is symmetrical with Symmetrize option from mesh menu. I am talking about selected islands, not all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatically unwrapping  identical geometry pieces one by one should produce identical UV layouts.
I.e. if you have a row of identical parts of geometry, select one, do unwrap, select another, etc. Selecting all at once may produce alike, but different islands.

If geometry is not identical, I'm afraid you're stuck with manually scaling down to zero required vertexes.

Answer (score 5):

If you get the vertices close enough to prevent accidental merges, you can use the UV editor's "remove doubles" feature. It dosen't actually delete vertices like the 3d version, but it does perfectly stack them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this technique in tandem with the answers previously given here.

If I understand your question, there is a way you can perfectly snap multiple uv's to the same spot for perfect manipulation, which I figured out with some inspiration while trying to figure out this very same issue.

Using the 3D cursor (or in our case, the 2D cursor) we'll snap all of our desired selections to a single point. Here's my example, where you can see my similar UV's below:

[image]

Next, we'll use Blender's fancy-shmantsy cursor-snapping tools!

You can access Blender's Cursor-snapping tools using the hotkey <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> or through the UV dropdown right next to the image-browser

[image]

Finally, we can get to the goodies! When we try snapping with the method presented above, (the method is *Snapping > Selected to Cursor [Offset]*) Each UV will be moved by its exact centerpoint, landing directly on top of the 2D Cursor! (Brilliant, right? Don't you just love inspiration?) Inspiring examples below:

[image]

[image]

**Important Note**: Make absolutely certain that you don't choose the default *Selected to cursor* option, and instead choose the *Selected to Cursor (Offset)* option! That *Offset* is your lifeblood, my young padawan! If you forget to choose the one with offset, your UV will collapse into an infinitesimally small point and cease to be recognizable as anything other than the essence and epitome of your sheer and utter failure to read a storming stack-guide. It is entirely unrecoverable, regardless of how many wanton tears you shed for it.

<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> >  <kbd>7</kbd>

<kbd>L</kbd> while hovering over the desired UV to SELECT, and then you SPAM-SPAM-SPAM that <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> >  <kbd>7</kbd> combo, (pressing  <kbd>7</kbd> is just a faster way of clicking that little *Selected to cursor (Offset)* thingy, allowing you to bypass the fiddling trouble with the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all the UV islands, then in the *UV Editor* try *UV > Align* and *UV > Snap* to point.