# Creating a cleaner UV Map for Dice?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm working on a game which will require creating lots of different dice (different combinations of faces).

I can produce the meshes just fine, but when I go to UV unwrap them, they get all shifted out of place, which makes coloring them a lot trickier.

Since the indented parts just need to be one color, and the colored parts just need to be another, I'd like the mesh to just be a very neatly unfolded square.

Are there any tricks I can use to get my UV map to unfold more evenly and regularly?

Here is an example of what I am seeing. This is with a basic 6-sided dice that has pips. The real dice I want to do are even less regular, so the inside of them gets really wild.

[image]

Ideally, I'd want it to largely unfold things flat and more regularly (i.e., 6 mostly regular squares and and easier delineation between the indents that I could more or less just flood fill with color)

I'd like something that looks more like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of your mesh and current uv map, so we can get a better idea of your issue?

Comment: Check out the Quad Unwrap preinstalled Addon and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64578/30849).