# Is there an addon to automatically stacking similar (not necessarily the exactly the same) UV islands?

Tags: uv, add-on, uv-image-editor

Let's say pair of *similar* UV islands is such a pair, where you can take one of the UV islands, move around its vertices, and get exactly the same looking UV island as the second one.

Basically, I'm asking a very similar question to:  [Is there a way to overlay two similar UV islands with identical vertex count?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-two-similar-uv-islands-with-identical-vertex-count), but knowing from the answers there is no such functionality in a vanilla blender, I'm asking whether such addon exists.

I found that [Magic-UV copy+paste functionality](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV/wiki/Tutorial#copypaste-uv) is close, but it tends to rearrange the vertices seemingly randomly sometimes, making it unusable in many cases.
[image]
[image]
The functionality I'm looking for:

1. Select similar UV islands you would like to stack.
2. Press "Stack UV islands"
3. Every selected UV island now inherits the shape from the firstly selected UV island, then rotates/scales to occupy the same texels.

Is there such an add-on?